# How to use if clauses in ON condition of a MySQL-Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join

I want to use two `IF` clauses in an `ON` condition of a MySQL `join`. This is my not working code:

```
$db->joins = 'JOIN st_users as users ON
                IF(messages.toUserID = 0, messages.userID = users.ID,
                    IF(messages.userID = 2, messages.toUserID = users.ID, messages.userID = users.ID)
                    )';
```

Why its not working? Wrong syntax?

Comment: Well, the query has no beginning.

Comment: I know ;) the problem is only the Join-line...

Comment: You don't know that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` returns a single value, while the `on` clause should be followed with a condition. You could use a series of `or` and `and` operators to construct the logic you want:

```
JOIN st_users as users 
ON   (messages.toUserID = 0 AND 
      messages.userID = users.ID) OR
     (messages.toUserID != 0 AND 
      messages.userID = 2 AND 
      messages.toUserID = users.ID) OR
     (messages.toUserID != 0 AND 
      messages.userID != 2 AND 
      messages.userID = users.ID)
```

Comment: I think you did it! Let me test it and you get your vote. But why the IF-clause isnt working I dont understand - could you explain me again please?

Comment: @user1711384 `if` returns a single value (based on conditions). You can't have `JOIN x ON if ()` just like you can't have `JOIN x ON 7`.

Answer (score 1):

As you always join to `users.ID` you might rewrite the `IF` to `CASE` returning a single value:

```
FROM messages 
JOIN st_users AS users 
  ON CASE
        WHEN messages.toUserID = 0 THEN messages.userID 
        WHEN messages.userID = 2   THEN messages.toUserID
        ELSE                            messages.userID
     END = users.ID
```

You could that also with for IF, but CASE is Standard SQL :-)

```
FROM messages 
JOIN st_users as users
  ON IF(messages.toUserID = 0, messages.userID,
        IF(messages.userID = 2, messages.toUserID, messages.userID)
       )  = users.ID
```